# Invalidate session in Grails

Tags: grails, session-timeout

In my Grails app I use `session.invalidate()` to deal with a timeout. When a user is redirected to the timeout page due to inactivity the session is invalidated.

My problem is that when the user goes back, the session is somehow restored. I've tried adding

```
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

as well as

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Expires","-1");
%>
```

to my gsp's to prevent the session from being reloaded, but it's not working. Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'user goes back'?? == 'javascript:history.go(-1)' ?

Comment: When the user goes back, is the session still active on page resfresh?

Comment: are you sure, that the page is not just cached? otherwise you must be invalidating a wrong session. try to check the sessionID, when you invalidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I wound up using was to add an isInvalid attribute to the servlet context.